# Search API from external site

Tags: product, admin, search

I'm very new to Magento and am trying to figure out/setup a search API for the products in our catalog for an external site.

How do I enable the API in Magento to be able to call GET /api/rest/products?q=hat, which would return all hats in our list of products?

Another example, GET /api/rest/products?q=shoes, which would return all shoes in our list of products.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that magento's api has no search methods.

You can try searching products using filters:

```
$filters = array(
    'name' => array('like'=>'zol%')
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

There are some extensions but they are not free. For example [this one](http://www.magecorner.com/magento-search-api/).

But you also can extend magento api by your own. This [manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html) could help you.